# CSS Hover: Hover text is not working in Chrome (works in safari)

Tags: css, google-chrome

The hover action works in chrome in my local files, but when I upload the CSS online, the hover within Chrome stops working. It works within Safari however. I've looked up suggestions with people having a similar issue, but all the 'fixes' are not working with mine.

```
[contentEditable=true]{
    color: black;
    font-family: "Verste-Regular"; 
    font-size: 14rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    outline: none;       
}

[contenteditable]:hover:after {
    content: ' Click & type here to test...';
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: "nimbus-sans-extended",sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    color: #5406ff;
    top: 10%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
}

[contenteditable]:focus:after {
    content: '';
}
```

Comment: Your CSS [works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/mcuq3aqy/) (tested in Chrome). *"but all the 'fixes' are **now** working with mine"* - Do you mean *not* working with yours?

Comment: Yes, I did mean that, and thanks for your comment. Seems like there is something wrong with my chrome, it works periodically and the issue is not within the code.